# java script's alert box is not getting displayed from code behind file before redirecting user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to implement a functionality in which first I have to show Java Script from code behind file and then user needs to be redirected to other page.

I have used both

```
this.Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('some text')</script>");
```

and

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();
```

but none of them were showing alert box
the code snippet is as :

```
//approach 1
    this.Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('some text')</script>");
  SPUtility.Redirect(string.Empty, SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, this.Context);

//approach 2
String csname1 = "PopupScript";
                Type cstype = this.GetType();

                // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
                ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

                // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
                if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
                {
                    StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
                    cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('You do not have Access to perform any action.') </");
                    cstext1.Append("script>");

                    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
                }
  SPUtility.Redirect(string.Empty, SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, this.Context);
```

but none of them shows alert box

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the approach you're trying to use will not work, because the redirect will take place before the page itself is actually written to the response. One way you could possibly circumvent this is to perform the redirect in Javascript:

```
StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript>");
cstext1.Append("alert('You do not have Access to perform any action.');");
cstext1.Append("window.location = '/';");
cstext1.Append("</script>");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
```

And then skip the `SPUtility.Redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

These methods registers and adds the script block to the page. So it will fire after the page is rendered from the server. In your case you are redirecting to some other page while the script is registered on the previous page.

So it would not fire on the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('Some Text')", true);
```

If you are using update panel..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel1, typeof(string), "alertScript", string.Format("alert('Some Text');", Session["myVariable"]), true);
```

Comment: Thanks @jameem I had done this but still not getting alert box